# Jssor thumbnail slider thumbnails not showing up

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

I am trying to create a thumbnail slider but thumbnail is not showing up. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
i am using non-jquery version of jssor slider and trying to use skin 16

Please help.

here is my test slider
http://innohome.kr/jssorslider/slider3.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the problem. But you are using a very old version of jssor slider.

Please use the latest version and update responsive code as follows, it will work as you need then.

```
        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_slider3.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider3.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
            else
                $JssorUtils$.$Delay(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);

        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
```